# Change text of a tag when an option selected using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make translations on my small site using Javascript.
I would like to change tag content by its ID or smth like that. I am not sure how should I do, but I kinda understand how it works...
I want to create files with strings & translations for each langauge.

So, there is a select tag which has who options...

```
    <select>
<option id="RU">Russian</option>
<option id="EN">English</option>
</select>
```

And there is content which has to be translated dependingly on selected option...

```
<div>
<span id="stringName">Your Name EN</span>: Viktor
<span id="stringPhone">Your Phone EN</span>: +7 900 00 00 00
<span id="stringEmail">Your E-mail EN</span>: the_great_russia@russia.ru
</div>
```

And localization files like...

**ru.js**

```
stringName: "Your Name RU"
stringPhone: "Your Phone RU"
stringEmail: "Your E-mail RU"
```

**en.js**

```
stringName: "Your Name EN"
stringPhone: "Your Phone EN"
stringEmail: "Your E-mail EN"
```

I have searched for what I need, but couldn't find.

Hope you will help me :) Thanks.

Comment: you may want a `change` event listener, and change the span's `innerHTML` in that change event listener

Comment: by the way, ru.js and en.js are not valid javascript, so, that's going to be an issue for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example of how you can get this to work using a change event on the select and a few global objects containing your language strings.

For your own site you can move the language objects to their own files and include them into the page

```js
var langRU = {
  stringName: "Your Name RU",
  stringPhone: "Your Phone RU",
  stringEmail: "Your E-mail RU"
};

var langEN = {
  stringName: "Your Name EN",
  stringPhone: "Your Phone EN",
  stringEmail: "Your E-mail EN"
};

function changeLang(lang) {
  document.querySelectorAll('[lang-change]').forEach(function(el) {
    el.innerText = window['lang'+lang][el.getAttribute('lang-change')];
  });
}

changeLang('EN');
```

```html
<select onchange="changeLang(this.value)">
  <option value="RU">Russian</option>
  <option value="EN" selected>English</option>
</select>

<br><br><br>

<div>
  <span lang-change="stringName">Your Name</span>: Viktor<br>
  <span lang-change="stringPhone">Your Phone</span>: +7 900 00 00 00<br>
  <span lang-change="stringEmail">Your E-mail</span>: the_great_russia@russia.ru<br>
</div>
```

Comment: The `lang` attribute is intended to contain a language tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang).

Comment: @NateWhittaker - Absolutely! Thanks for the great catch. I've updated attribute to `lang-change`